# Jquery html() method to get <li> html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an unordered list in my HTML

```
<ul>
   <li><div class="container1"><h2>list 1</h2></div></li>
   <li><div class="container2"><h2>list 2</h2></div></li>
   <li><div class="container3"><h2>list 3</h2></div></li>
</ul>
```

I want to get a particular `<li>` html using Jquery `html()` method

```
console.log($(".container1").closest('li').html()); // returns code from the div
output : <div class="container"><h2>list 1</h2></div>
```

I want the output as `<li><div class="container1"><h2>list 1</h2></div></li>` including `<li>` tags.

If I go one level above to `closest('ul')` its returning all the 3 li elements.

**JSFiddle** : http://jsfiddle.net/W4QfJ/417/

Comment: Provided printing HTML content of that <li> in console is not the end-result here, what do you want to do with that <li> element next? If you lose the `.html()` at the end, you will have a perfectly good jQuery selector holding that same <li> element. You can do with it what you would do with any jQuery selection: remove it, move some place else, add after it, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `$(".container1").closest('li')[0].outerHTML` (I think it is compatible for most browsers-You probably need to check for IE)

Comment: Can you please explain why do we need the [0] index after closest li

Comment: [0] gets the DOM element and then outerHTML is a property of that

Comment: the [0] gets the actual element represented by the jQuery object.  outerHtml is not a jQuery method, but a native javascript method.

Comment: @budhavarapuranga You can also use `$(".container1").closest('li').prop("outerHTML")`

Answer (score 2):

So, this is more of a documentation than the answer as [@tabz100](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30512843/jquery-html-method-to-get-li-html/30512908#30512908) has the asnwer.

Few ways of getting the outer HTML (in the order of *my* preference):

```
// 1)
$(".container1").closest('li').prop("outerHTML");
// 2)
$(".container1").closest('li')[0].outerHTML;
// 3)
$(".container1").closest('li').wrap("<div></div>").parent().html();
```